# genealogytree package: left align timeflow=down tree

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, genealogytree

I try to make a family tree using the genealogytree package. 
I would like to follow the downwards timeflow but still left align every generation. 
Any idea how to do so?
I want the males to be directly under each other
Minimal code example (the complete version is huge with lot of additional informations, so I want to be able to follow the direct line on the left):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
node size=4cm,
level size=2cm,
level distance=1cm,
timeflow=down,
]
sandclock{
 child{ 
 g[male]{Johann Christian}
 p[female]{Maria Katharina Bürmann}
  child{
  g[male]{Johann Christoffer} 
  p[female]{Ilse Marie Cords}
   child{
   g[male]{Johann Friedrich Christian}
   p[female]{Anna Maria Kopp}
   }
  }
 }
 parent{
  g[male]{Hans Meyer}
 } 
}
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, for those interested: pivot option for g does the trick.

```
g[pivot,male]{Some Name}
```